# Xcode manage "Core data" records

Tags: ios, database, xcode, sqlite, core-data

In my project i use core data libary. I have created Entity at `.xcdatamodeld` file and in my code i created a lot of records:

```
        let managedContext = AppDelegate().managedObjectContext

        let person = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        person.setValue("name", forKey: "plugin_",")

        do {
             try managedContext.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
        }
```

But where do i find stuff in Xcode to show all records at my database, delete and edit them like [mysql workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data uses SQLite under the hood. Xcode does not provide any tool to manage sqlite. So you need external tool/browser that manages sqlite.

Comment: The file is in Documents folder of the app sandbox. The simple way to find it is to use this app http://simpholders.com.